# Animate view during navigation controller transition in iOS7

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, core-animation, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

In view for my view controller I have a animation running on the time. However when user swipes the view from the left and slides it to the right (to go back to preview view controller in UINavigationController) the animation stops. It's crucial for me to make this animation work even when sliding. How can I ensure that?

Comment: Are you using +[UIView animetaWithDuration…] to animate views?

Comment: I've experienced common trouble some time ago. I've solve it with refactoring from UIView animation to CALayer-level animations. In other words, I've migrated from [UIView animateWithDuration…] to CAkeyframeanimation